# What are "voting irregularities"?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting, account-suspension

I found a [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1173806/math-attack?tab=topactivity) that was answered several of my questions suspended for "voting irregularities" ... is there any information what "voting irregularities" means?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98467/196432, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/196432

Comment: The suspension now says it is due to rule violations. One wonders what happened